# Embedding a ruby object into coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, coffeescript

I'm going to try and simplify a previous question: I have a products page at http://pants.telegraphbranding.com/t/women/long-sleeve. When you hover over a product's list of thumbnails the main image should change for that product. But right now, every product on the page is trying to change. To get a unique id of for product I'm using:

```
<div id="main-image" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
  <%= link_to large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image"), product, :itemprop => 'url' %>
</div><!-- main-image-->
```

How do I incorporate the data-productid="<%= product.id %> into my coffeescript file?

```
add_image_handlers = ->

thumbnails = ($ '#product-images ul.thumbnails')
($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumb', ($ '#main-image img').attr('src')
thumbnails.find('li').eq(0).addClass 'selected'
thumbnails.find('a').on 'click', (event) ->
  ($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumb', ($ event.currentTarget).attr('href')
  ($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumbId', ($ event.currentTarget).parent().attr('id')
  ($ this).mouseout ->
    thumbnails.find('li').removeClass 'selected'
    ($ event.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass 'selected'
false

thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseenter', (event) ->
  ($ '#main-image img').attr 'src', ($ event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href')

thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseleave', (event) ->
  ($ '#main-image img').attr 'src', ($ '#main-image').data('selectedThumb')

show_variant_images = (variant_id) ->
  ($ 'li.vtmb').hide()
  ($ 'li.vtmb-' + variant_id).show()
  currentThumb = ($ '#' + ($ '#main-image').data('selectedThumbId'))
  if not currentThumb.hasClass('vtmb-' + variant_id)
    thumb = ($ ($ 'ul.thumbnails li:visible.vtmb').eq(0))
    thumb = ($ ($ 'ul.thumbnails li:visible').eq(0)) unless thumb.length > 0
    newImg = thumb.find('a').attr('href')
    ($ 'ul.thumbnails li').removeClass 'selected'
    thumb.addClass 'selected'
    ($ '#main-image img').attr 'src', newImg
    ($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumb', newImg
    ($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumbId', thumb.attr('id')

update_variant_price = (variant) ->
  variant_price = variant.data('price')
  ($ '.price.selling').text(variant_price) if variant_price

$ ->
 add_image_handlers()
 show_variant_images ($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').eq(0).attr('value') if 
($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').length > 0
($ '#product-variants input[type="radio"]').click (event) ->
show_variant_images @value
update_variant_price ($ this)
```

Obviously I would like the coffeescript to pull out the unique id's of each main image so that the image change only happens for that specific image.

I appreciate it. Sorry for the length.

Comment: Is this the same as your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419112/inserting-ruby-object-ids-into-coffeecript-via-html5-hooks)?

Comment: More or less. I simplified it and reformatted the coffeescript.

Comment: Won't You be so kind to replace `<div id="main-image" data-productid="12">` with more appropriate `<div class="main-image" data-productid="12">`?

Then You will be able to enumerate all the corresponding images with `$(".main-image")`, iterate the array and pull out some `.data "productid"` values.

Comment: @kirushik Absolutely. I just changed it. Do you think that's causing any problems?

Comment: You can't have duplicate `id` attributes in HTML, all bets are off if you attempt to treat looks-like-HTML-but-is-not-valid-HTML as HTML.

Comment: @kirushik Would you mind giving me any more details? How would I enumerate all the images? Thank you very much.

Comment: @jtrinker It is strictly against the standart. And jQuery's `$("#id")` returns single element even if there are several of them.

Comment: @jtrinker I've run `$.each($(".main-image"), function(index,elem){console.log($(elem).data("productid"))})` in DevTools console. It outputs all the id's of your clothes one-by-one.

Comment: Great, thank you. i changed the improper ids to classes. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @jtrinker Ok, that means it's proper time for me to pack up my answer as a whole (and for You — to accept it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, one should enumerate all the elements with `data-productid` properties.

For this very page `var elements = $(".main-image")` should be enough. *(Please keep in mind the class selector here. Original page contained id selectors, and caused roubles and havoc. Fixed for now.)*

Then one should iterate over achieved values: `$.each(elements, function(index, element){...})` should do the trick.

And at last it is possible to retrieve `data-productid` values from elements (in `$.each` loop, I mean): `$(element).data("productid")` will return required values. *(Please note `$(element)` part here. `element.data(...)` won't work because we enumerated jQuery accessors, not actual elements — and they need to be dereferenced before use.)*

Combine that into something like `$.each($(".main-image"), function(index,elem){console.log($(elem).data("productid"))})` *(tested in Chrome DevTools against actual page, seemed to work)* — voilà, problem solved!

Comment: I got my coffeescript loop working, it's pulling out all the productids. Thank you very much for your help. How would you attach that to the above coffeescript file so that it runs that cs on each productid?

Comment: @jtrinker I don't get what do You mean with 'cs', sorry. Perharps You just should substitute `console.log` with required operational function.

Comment: I just meant the primary coffeescript file. How do I apply each of the data elements in the array created with `$.each($(".main-image"), function(index,elem {console.log($(elem).data("productid"))})` to be run separately in the coffeescript file I posted in my initial question?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. You run `console.log` on each of your productid's one by one. What stops YOu from replacing that call with another function?

Comment: I apologize for the questions, feel free to move on. I tried adding `$.each $(".main-image"), (index, elem) ->` to the very top of the coffeescript file, above `add_image_handlers = ->` And then `$(elem).data("productid")` in various places, such as directly above the `show_variant_images = (variant_id) ->` function, as well as a couple other places, but it just kills the hover effect on the page, doesn't fix anything.

Comment: It turns out that I didn't need to loop through the main-image divs at all. I simply needed to change 

`thumbnails = ($ '#product-images ul.thumbnails')
($ '#main-image').data 'selectedThumb', ($ '#main-image img').attr('src')`

to:

`thumbnails = ($ '.product-images ul.thumbnails')
  ($ '.main-image').data 'selectedThumb', 'productid', $(this).find('img')`

So essentially just ('.main-image img') to $(this)

Thanks though.